# Хитрый SQL запрос

Tags: php, pdo

Есть две таблицы `users` и `ticket`. В `users` хранится информация о пользователях. В `ticket` хранятся заявки пользователей. Информация о заявителе и исполнителе хранится в виде `ID` пользователя из таблицы `users`. Все это богатство вывожу в таблицу запросом, где отображается исполнитель (ФИО):

```
$ticket = array();

$select_ticket = $dbquery->prepare("SELECT id_ticket, tic_id_rand,
                    ticket_title, id_status, status_name, name_service, 
                    ticket_date_open,
                    ticket_deadline, name_prio, first_name, middle_name, 
                    surname, 
                  ticket_executor 
                  FROM ticket, users, ticket_status, priority, service 
                  WHERE ticket.ticket_status=ticket_status.id_status AND 
                    ticket.ticket_executor=users.users_id AND 
                    ticket.ticket_service=service.id_service AND 
                    ticket.ticket_priority=priority.id_prio");

$select_ticket->execute();
while($row = $select_ticket->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $ticket[] = $row;
}

return $ticket;
```

В таблице выводится все как надо. Но встал вопрос, необходимо дополнительно выводить поле `Заявитель`. Пробовал добавить:

```
ticket.ticket_customer=users.user_id
```

Такой вариант в запросе не работает. В таблице `users` хранится только ФИО 
пользователя. А в таблице `ticket` поля имеют такой вид: Исполнитель - `ticket_executor`, Заявитель `ticket_customer`.

То есть получается мне надо дважды провести сравнение разных столбцов из `ticket` с одним столбцом в `users`
Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вся информация должна быть в вопросе, а не комментариях под ним

Comment: Так нажми "править" и добавь всё в вопрос

Comment: П - Программист, который не знает соединения таблиц - не прораммист

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо в таком случае использовать соединения между таблицами

```
$sql    = "SELECT  user1.login, user2.login 
                        FROM `tickets` tickets
                        LEFT JOIN `users` user1 ON user1.id = tickets.executor_id
                        LEFT JOIN `users` user2 ON user2.id = tickets.customer_id
                        ";
```

В таком случае, можно тянуть инфу которая соединяется по разным полям в tickets.

--

```
$sql = "SELECT  id_ticket, tic_id_rand, ticket_title, 
                id_status, status_name, name_service, ticket_date_open, 
                ticket_deadline, ticket_executor,
                user_executor.name_prio,
                user_customer.name_prio
        FROM    ticket ticket, 
                ticket_status ticket_status, 
                priority priority, 
                service service
        LEFT JOIN `users` user_executor ON user_executor.id = ticket.ticket_executor
        LEFT JOIN `users` user_customer ON user_customer.id = ticket.ticket_customer
        WHERE   ticket.ticket_status=ticket_status.id_status 
                AND 
                ticket.ticket_executor=users.users_id 
                AND 
                ticket.ticket_service=service.id_service 
                AND 
                ticket.ticket_priority=priority.id_prio";
```

Comment: Смотрел в эту сторону, но пока в голове не укладывается как это все к моему запросу применить (((

Comment: @LikeSD Вам необходимо для начала для всех таблиц расставить алиасы, а потом применять внешние соединнеия. Я в пример добавил еще один запрос, но там необходимо алиасы расставить, и будет работать.

Comment: @LikeSD Кстати, если поля customer и executor всегда заполнены в таблице то писать left join, как вам тут предлагают, совершенно не нужно, просто пишите как и все остальное через запятую в from только с алиасами, что бы можно было отличить две копии таблицы в запросе друг от друга (кстати, алиасы я рекомендую использовать всегда, их делаешь покороче и не надо выписывать имена таблиц вечно. типа `from ....,tickets T, users U1, users U2 where U1.id=T.customer and U2.id=T.executor ...`

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Натолкнули на правильное решение.

```
SELECT T.id_ticket, T.tic_id_rand, T.ticket_title, id_status, 
status_name, name_service, T.ticket_date_open, T.ticket_deadline, 
name_prio, U1.first_name as u1_first_name, U1.middle_name, U1.surname, 
U2.first_name as u2_first_name, U2.middle_name, U2.surname FROM users 
U1, users U2, ticket T, ticket_status, priority, service WHERE 
T.ticket_status=ticket_status.id_status AND 
T.ticket_executor=U1.users_id AND T.ticket_customer=U2.users_id AND 
T.ticket_service=service.id_service AND 
T.ticket_priority=priority.id_prio
```